# chrome print preview doesnt work properly on windows but works fine on mac

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

On chrome for mac the print preview works fine but when I test it on windows 10 it fails to display some elements of the page. here are the two pages, as you see on mac the ball with the line through it displays but on windows its just a little box. any help would be appreciated, im at a loss for whats causing this issue.
[pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXxz0.png)

[picutres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnBQz.png)